# update new added form data and post to server

Tags: reactjs

I am writing three components, one is form, one is form_list, I can add new form to form_list when I click add_new_form, now how to get the form_list’s data when any old form's value change or add new form, I need to post these data to server, but I don’t know how to update it

```
var Form = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <section>
                <input name="name" value={this.props.form.name} />
                <input name="age" value={this.props.form.age} />
            </section>
        )
    }
});

var FormList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var form_list = this.props.form_list.map(function(form) {
            return (
                <form form={form} />
            )
        });
        return (
                <div>
                    {form_list}
                </div>
        )
    }
});

var RegisterForm = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {form_list: [{id: Date.now()}]};    # at first, there is one empty form for user input
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <section>
                <FormList form_list={this.state.form_list} />
                <button className="add_new_form">add_new_form</button>
                <button className="post_data"></button>
            </section>
        )
    }
})
```

Comment: So you basically want to submit an arbitrary amount of `form`s at once?

Comment: yeah, I just want to submit arbitary amount of forms at once

Comment: You would have to pull all the data out of the forms to submit them together in one POST request, better use one `form` in which you dynamically add `sections`s (remember to also give every form field a unique `name`)

Comment: you mean I have to like use jquery or anything that get the all form's data, and put it all together, and then use ajax post to server, right? there is no way update the together_data when input data into any form?

Comment: Exactly, there is no way to upload multiple forms at once, you would have to make multiple requests to do that natively (which is not possible).

Comment: sorry, I think you misunderstand what I said, the "form" in my code ,just one group, I will handle this formdata_list in server,

Comment: But it looks like you actually create multiple html `form` elements, and expect the submit button to submit them all.

Comment: no, in fact, it just like: one teacher have multiple children, I want to add one teacher and multiple children once, and I use ajax post json data, not form type data.

Comment: Ooh then I actually misunderstood this part.. but still you have to put it all together into one object manually, using jquery or something like that.